# Where is the fuel pressure test port located on the 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan?

Tags: dodge, fuel-injection, fuel-injectors, grand-caravan, fuel-pressure

I purchased the Innova 3640 Professional Fuel Injection Pressure Tester, and I want to test the fuel pressure on my 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan.

Where is the fuel pressure test port located under the hood?

---

**Details:**

- **Year:** 2012
- **Make:** Dodge
- **Model:** Grand Caravan SXT 2WD
- **Engine:** [V6 - 3.6L 3604cc 220ci FLEX MFI vin G type ERB - 4 valve DOHC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysler_Pentastar_engine#3.6L)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for the warm welcome! Do you have any idea by chance where I can find the fuel pressure test port?

Comment: Try calling your local Dodge dealer service department and ask. Either a straight answer will come forth or not.